# How to add dynamic styling using VueJs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I toggle designs using inputs?

```
<section id="assignment">
      <!-- 1) Fetch the user input and use it as a CSS class -->
      <!-- The entered class should be added to the below paragraph -->
      <input type="text" v-on:input="setUser" />
      <!-- (available classes: "user1", "user2") -->
      <p :class="{user}">
        Style me!
      </p>
      <button>Toggle Paragraph</button>
      <!-- 2) Use the "visible" and "hidden" classes to show/ hide the above paragraph -->
      <!-- Clicking the button should toggle between the two options -->

      <!-- 3) Add dynamic inline styling to the below paragraph and let the user enter a background-color -->
      <input type="text" />
      <p>Style me inline!</p>
    </section>
```

I have already made user1 and user2 classes in css file, but when i try to output user as a class it is showing just user doesnot matter what i write in input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at following demo:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      bgcolor: null,
      toggle: false,
      users: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    classes() {
      return this.users.map(u => 'user' + u.id)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.users = json)
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.user1 {
  color: red;
}
.user2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <section id="assignment">
    <select v-model="user">
      <option v-for="(cls, i) in classes" :key="i">
        {{ cls }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" v-model="user" />
    <p :class="user">
      Style me!
    </p>
    <button @click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle Paragraph</button>
    <input v-model="bgcolor" type="color" />
    <p v-if="toggle" :style="`background-color: ${bgcolor};`">Style me inline!</p>
  </section>
</div>
```